# LDAP authentication from Windows AD to Linux virtual host

Tags: ldap, openldap

Scenario: I have an internal linux (Centos 5.6) server offering a virtual host, access to which I would like to restrict to users already authenticated on our internal Windows 2008 server. I need to pull back the user name once authenticated, to build a view package for the site.

I'm continually getting an error message in my logs:

```
[Tue Jul 26 14:16:19 2011] [warn] [client x.x.x.x] [17892] auth_ldap authenticate: user my.name authentication failed; URI / [ldap_search_ext_s() for user failed][Operations error]
```

My <VirtualHost> includes this within the <Directory> section:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Alpha Server"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative On
AuthLDAPUrl "ldap://windows.internal.server:389/ou=Mainusers,ou=SubUsers,ou=Others,dc=mydomainname,dc=extension"
require valid-user
```

I have tried "require ldap-user", "require ldap-group" and other permutations, all with the same result. Additionally, the page displays a 500 (internal server) error.

I have also set REFERRALS off in my /etc/openldap/ldap.conf file.

I've tried to search where I could be going wrong... is there something I'm missing that's glaringly obvious?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Kerberos is most certainly not less hassle.  Suggesting otherwise is just comical.

Active Directory does not allow anonymous binds.  You'll need to add an unprivileged account to your directory and then use the AuthLDAPBindBN and AuthLDAPBindPassword parameters.

Comment: You may want to keep comments on other answers as comments (once you gained enough reputation to comment on other posts) and out of your answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this one's for serverfault for starters.
You did **not** specify what the user attribute is. You should rather use Kerberos with mod_auth_kerb, if you are in an AD environment. This is less hassle and easier to utilize.